# Ansible: overide roles default values

Tags: ansible, jinja2, devops

I have got the following ansible directory layout

```
inventories/
   group_vars/     # common variables production and staging
      all
   production/
      hosts              
      group_vars/     
         all      # common to all production 
         groupN.yml
      host_vars/
         all     # common to all production 
         hostnameN.yml

   staging/
      hosts               
      group_vars/     
         all      # common to all staging 
         groupN.yml
      host_vars/
         all     # common to all staging 
         hostnameN.yml      

site.yml
production.yml
staging.yml

roles/
    docker/
         defaults
             # let's assume there defaults contain default_docker_version=a.b.c
         tasks
         ...
    webtier/
```

- My questions are:

*- How do I override the values in roles/common/default using host specific values?*

That is, I want to have the default value of roles specific to the environment.

Example I want production hosts to have docker version of x.y.z and staging have docker_version of a.b.c

I tried adding the variable to the host_vars - but ansible is still not able to find it.

---

*- Is there an improvement on the structure layout that can be made?*

Answer (score 2):

You can have the value of docker version in your inventory specific to the environments. Then while calling the role in your playbook you need to pass the value to override the default value within the role.

Below is snippet to call the role from playbook by overriding the value

```
 roles:
   - { role: roles/common, docker_version: "{{ docker_version }}" }
```

docker_version is variable which is passed to the role to override the value and its value coming from the inventory of playbook.

> refer [here](https://gist.github.com/ekreutz/301c3d38a50abbaad38e638d8361a89e) for checking the precedence of the variables in ansible, it's very helpful.

Comment: It does not seem to work. 
I tried 
` roles:
  - role: docker
    docker_version: " {{ docker_version }} " `
I tried but ansible throws - `unhandled exception occurred while templating ' {{ docker_version }}`

Answer (score 2):

> Q: *"How do I override the values in roles/common/default using **host-specific values**?"*

A: For *staging* put the variables into the directory

```
inventories/staging/host_vars
```

For *production* put the variables into the directory

```
inventories/production/host_vars
```

For example

```
$ cat inventories/production/hosts
prod-001
prod-002
prod-003

$ cat inventories/production/hosts/host_vars/prod-001
docker_version: "x.y.z"

$ cat inventories/production/hosts/host_vars/prod-002
docker_version: "x.y.z"

$ cat inventories/production/hosts/host_vars/prod-003
docker_version: "x.y.z"
```

It would be more efficient to use **group-specific values**. For example

```
$ cat inventories/production/hosts
[group_01]
prod-001
prod-002
prod-003

$ cat inventories/production/group_vars/group_01
docker_version: "x.y.z"
```

, or **all**. For example

```
$ cat inventories/production/group_vars/all
docker_version: "x.y.z"
```

> Q: *" Is there an **improvement** in the structure layout that can be made?"*

A: Your case is [Alternative Directory Layout](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#alternative-directory-layout) with *production* and *staging* inventory in separate directories. It's necessary to [configure inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-host-list). For example

```
ansible-playbook -i inventories/staging/hosts site.yml
```

In this case, the inventory variables in the directories *staging/hosts/host_vars* and *staging/hosts/group_vars* are used. It's possible to test it

```
ansible-inventory -i inventories/staging/hosts --list
```

There are other [**options**](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#best-practices) rather than improvements depending on your use-cases.

---

Notes

- *inventories/group_vars/all* is useless
- *inventories/production/host_vars/all* is useless (staging the same)

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. 
Why is inventories/group_vars/all not valid? If i wanted common properties between production and staging - how would i achieve it?

Comment: What hosts would use inventories/group_vars/all? Why do you separate inventories when you want common properties?

Comment: There is one specific property that both production and staging hosts share. And I was hoping to achieve it someway

Comment: At what preference level would you like to share it? Defaults <-> Extra vars? For example, use [ansible-pull](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-pull.html#ansible-pull) at the beginning of a playbook triggered at remote and you can build any architecture you can imagine if you want to.

Comment: share as defaults

Comment: Share defaults in the roles. It's not productive. Such a discussions should be moved to chat. I quit here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202042/discussion-between-rpt-and-vladimir-botka).

Comment: One last query - I've got vault file under inventory/staging/group_vars. I am trying to access the vault secret from inventory/staging/group_vars/all.yml but it throws undefined. Is it related to directory structure? Both those files are under the same directory inventory/staging/group_vars

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55048340/using-vault-in-playbooks/

Comment: that link does not seem to answer my query