# How can I encrypt sensitive data in playbooks with Ansible Vault?

Tags: ansible

My goal is to add task

```yaml
- name: Log into DockerHub
  command: docker_login
  username: myname
  password: ********
```

I tried to add to vars

```yaml
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: '{{ ansible_playbook_python }}'
    image_name: docker-nextjs-dev
    secrets: !vault |
    $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
    66386565316361613962653530666266613632656366333032636661363765386462373038376438
```

and changed

```yaml
- name: Log into DockerHub
  command: docker_login
  username: docker
  password: "{{ secrets }}"
```

When I run

```
ansible-playbook --ask-vault-pass secrets.yml
```

and put my password

```
ERROR! A playbook must be a list of plays, got a <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleUnicode'> instead

The error appears to be in '/home/miki/prac/ansible-for-kubernetes/hello-go-automation/secrets.yml': line 1, column 1, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
```

How do I pass `secrets.yaml` as var in playbook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: ***"How to pass secrets.yaml as var in the playbook?"***

A: You can't provide the vault password *`"as var in the playbook"`*. See [*Running a Playbook With Vault*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_vault.html#running-a-playbook-with-vault).
In your example, you use a file to provide the vault password

```bash
shell> ansible-playbook --ask-vault-pass secrets.yml
```

This is wrong. Use the option `--vault-password-file` if you want to provide the vault password from a file

```bash
shell> ansible-playbook --vault-password-file secrets.yml
```

See also: [*Using vault in playbooks*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55048340/using-vault-in-playbooks/55050139#55050139).

---

The error

> ERROR! A playbook must be a list of plays, ...

is a syntax problem and is not related to the Ansible vault.

---

Once you decided how to provide the vault password the Ansible vault works as expected. For example, encrypt a string (the vault password provided via environment ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE)

```bash
shell> ansible-vault encrypt_string foo_bar_baz
Encryption successful
!vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          37623535633063303662346335316537333831643539353037393731373438356634643561623064
          6335636535393836633364396433663131653561313261380a323664386133633861323863393834
          34636666333431623632366134663133383930653135393164353732373634343631313733396664
          3537666431376432300a643666393733383262613438313563396662323933303465613530666565
          3934
```

Use it in a play

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    passwd: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          37623535633063303662346335316537333831643539353037393731373438356634643561623064
          6335636535393836633364396433663131653561313261380a323664386133633861323863393834
          34636666333431623632366134663133383930653135393164353732373634343631313733396664
          3537666431376432300a643666393733383262613438313563396662323933303465613530666565
          3934

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: passwd
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  passwd: foo_bar_baz
```

---

You can put the variable into a file

```yaml
shell> cat passwd.yml 
passwd: foo_bar_baz
```

Encrypt the file

```bash
shell> ansible-vault encrypt passwd.yml 
Encryption successful
```

```bash
shell> cat passwd.yml 
$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
63383736626439363062383861363933366266653731303833343862663764303763663763336338
3933373263663764323433653264633565613061643366350a613632646137343866626566393563
35326431303061633734343538613339636466313036373931613130323835656336643665343936
6463306466373639370a636239316135653933386532346536623761336561313739363362353534
34373763363735303136373766343838663566393039353132333032646139353235
```

Use it in a play

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars_files:
    - passwd.yml

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: passwd
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  passwd: foo_bar_baz
```

---

**Best practice** is to limit the scope of the secrets. For example, limit the scope of the variable *passwd* to the task where you use it. Put the password into a plaintext

```bash
shell> cat passwd.txt
foo_bar_baz
```

Encrypt the file

```bash
shell> ansible-vault encrypt passwd.txt
Encryption successful
```

```bash
shell> cat passwd.txt
$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
33313232663733653465373064353230646332393366356433373333396430623138336162366366
6238316131666635623664323630316430393361383365370a633934323330386233353931333431
64666133323238323462383039626261643066383866353438363964383634376164366463303435
3133643766343763330a653563643338653638393934396131663066306634386235626230646237
6439
```

and use it in a task

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: passwd
      vars:
        passwd: "{{ lookup('file', 'passwd.txt') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  passwd: foo_bar_baz
```